# Android, Using AppModule context at whole the app using dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

According code below:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
private Application application;

public AppModule(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}

@Singleton
@Provides
Context providesContext() {
    return application;
  }

@Singleton
@Provides
IAppDbHelper providesAppDbHelper() {
    // a SQLiteOpenHelper class 
    return new AppDbHelper(application);
  }
}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
void inject(SecondActivity secondActivity);
IAppDBHelper providesIAppDBHelper();
}
```

MainActivity:
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    IAppDBHelper helper;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getComponent()
            .inject(this);
    // It's OK
    helper.getWritable().execSQL("XXX");

    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
}
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Inject
IAppDBHelper helper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    // nullPointer on helper
    helper.getWritable().execSQL("XXX");
}
}
```

After `inject`ing my `AppComponent` inside my `SecondActivity`, `nullPointer` error fixes but my question is do I have to `inject` My `AppComponent` every time I want inject `IAppDbHelper`? So what does `@Singleton` and injecting in inside my `MainActivity` mean? Doesn't should they inject that `IAppDbHelper` for my `SecondActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get your component and inject *each class that Android creates*. This typically means all Activities, Fragments, and Views. Dagger can't create those classes, so the only way Dagger knows about the externally-created instance is when you pass it into the `inject` method on your Component.

During the injection, all `@Inject` fields on MainActivity and SecondActivity will be provided, and any instances that Dagger creates will also have their dependencies injected, and so forth all the way down the line. This means that you won't usually need your Component directly outside of your externally-created classes like Activities and Fragments, or (of course) your Application instance where you create the Component instance itself.

`@Singleton` does mean that the instance will remain the same between MainActivity, SecondActivity, and any future instances of MainActivity or SecondActivity that Android may create as you background the app. However, *you still need to request injection* for those classes as Android creates them, in order to receive that same instance that you've guaranteed with `@Singleton`.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, so do I have to pass a `Context` argument for each **logic** classes that needs `IAppDbHelper` to inject it again? My problem is using those `singleton` dependencies inside classes with no context.